# Error generating a controller with a "cookies" action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, controller, action, reserved-words

I'm new programming in Rails and I got an error I don't understand.

When I create a controller with the action cookies like:

```
rails g controller Pages home about cookies
```

I get a NoMethodError in PagesController when loading any page:

undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #9):

```
def set_request_method_cookie
    if request.get?
      cookies.delete(:request_method)
    else
      cookies[:request_method] = request.request_method
end
```

I was wondering if the word "cookies" is a reserved word but I don't find it in the list. If not, how can I fix it using the word cookies as an action? Thanks

A screenshot of the error https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUVKn.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is reserved to interact with browser's cookie.

You could keep `cookies` url but route it to a different action name like `cookies_action`, provide your routes if you want more details. [This may help](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)